# Какие есть варианты реализации добавления товара с модификаторами в корзину?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Всем привет! Интересует вопрос как реализовать добавление товара с модификаторами в корзину так же как это сделано на сайтах Макдональдс, Яндекс еда и тп.

Как я понимаю эту схему:
Есть некий товар, у него есть кнопка, в которую вставлен id этого товара. При нажатии на кнопку через js достаем этот id и через ajax отправляем в php. В php проверяем что это именно идентификатор и достаем из БД все данные об этом товаре, в том числе и модификаторы, а далее выводим ответом в popup эти данные.

- Если это не правильная схема, поправьте меня пожалуйста.

И собственно сами вопросы: Как все это реализовать на php и js или в какую сторону гуглить? И как сделать это безопасным?

Тут указано про какие моменты я говорю выше на примере сайта Макдональдса.

[image: Схема на примере сайта Макдональдс]

Вот ссылки на сайты где это реализовано:

- https://mcdonalds.ru/
- https://www.delivery-club.ru/srv/KFC_spb?vendorCategoriesQuery=-2
- https://eda.yandex.ru/restaurant/mcdonalds_krasnoarmejskaja

Всем спасибо!

Comment: Еще зависит многое от того применяете ли вы фреймворк на клиенте (например Vue js, Ext js, React js).  Если применяете - то данные обо всех товарах со всеми модификаторами у вас сразу грузятся клиенту. А заказ на сервер отправляется всего один раз. Сходить 10 раз на сервер намного дольше чем один раз выгрузить на клиента всю информацию, если конечно у вас товаров меньше 500 конечно же

Comment: Фреймворков не применяю, а товаров в приложении не более 100 шт вместе с модификаторами. Еще один момент, наличие товаров часто меняются, то есть в момент пока клиент делает выбор, наличие может измениться и все равно придется сходить на сервер при добавлении товара в корзину и проверить его наличие.

Comment: Вот это плохой показатель :  "наличие товаров часто меняются" - у вас тогда должен стоять web socket server и уведомлять пользователей об изменяющемся количестве online. Товаров не более 100 шт - грузите их все с модификаторами в json формате, если они у вас все на одной странице могут уместиться

Comment: Для скорости вы можете закешировать сериализованный объект, который собрал все товары в себя. Выдергивая его из кеша вы его десериализуете и каждой позиции по id проставляете цену и остаток. В итоге вам не придется лезть в базу за дополнительными параметрами. Последний товар у вас не могут купить дважды - поэтому придется использовать транзакции и резервирование на 15 минут(время чтобы оплатить заказ) Это всего лишь рекомендации. Все зависит от навыков и бизнес задачи

Comment: Спасибо огромное буду думать как реализовать все это дело, сам что-то не додумал до онлайн оповещения.